# Sparse matrix multiplication struct

Tags: c

Is it possible to multiply 2 sparse matrices using this struct? If so can you give me any hints or a correct structure?

```
typedef struct node{
    int column;
    int value;
    int row;
    struct node *next;
} element;
```

Comment: You should be able to do it using *any* suitable *data-structure*. The actual implementation details of the data-structure (like using a linked list) is largely irrelevant.

Comment: This is a lot of memory usage. I suggest you use single variable of double pointers and access them. Memory allocation using `malloc`.

Comment: @tilz0R - The whole idea is to save memory by using a linked list - it's for a sparse matrix

Comment: @4386427 First of all, we must ask what is the size of matrix. Sparse matrix is not already defined size, but *most of entries are zero*. In case of 4x4 matrix, it is probably less memory if he uses my option, but if matrix is 10x10 or more then linked list might be efficient.

Comment: Actually i need for a 100x100

Comment: @tilz0R - no one would use such approach for small matrices like 4x4 or 10x10. It is for much bigger stuff.

Comment: @Gundal then your approach is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's probably possible since it seems capable of expressing a sparse matrix through a linked-list of elements. Each element would then correspond to a matrix cell, and carry the value for that cell.

It doesn't, of course, help in any way with the actual multiplication, which would involve searching such lists for the elements to multiply and add together.

I'm sure there are other, more advanced, data structures that make the implementation of multiplication more efficient.

Improvements to *this* data structure might include:

- Keeping elements sorted by row and/or column, to allow some optimizations when searching.
- Adding a top-level `Matrix` structure might make sense, it could for instance hold the overall dimensions of the matrix (which will allow quicker checks for size compatibility when multiplying).